# Importing Data in R based on Dates

Tags: r, excel

I want to import an excel file in `R`. The file however has columns such as `Jan-13`, `Jan14` and so on. These are the column headers. When I import the data using the `readxl` package, it by default converts the date into numbers. So my columns which should be dates are now numbers. 
I am using the code :

```
library(readxl)
data = read_excel("FileName", col_names = TRUE, skip = 0)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Change them in Excel to format="text'.

Comment: Could you include a small example of the numbers you are getting and the date-values you expect? You might want to read [Ask] and how to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) in order to get the best possible answer for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The date information is still there. It's just in the wrong format. This should work:

```
names(data) <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(names(data), origin="1899-01-01")), "%b%d")
```

Comment: The origin of date in Excel is dependent of the OS, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I saw that documentation too. I tried it both ways and got the same result though, which, for some reason, is exactly 1 day higher than the input dates. Does anyone have a tweak for that?